# How to ensure the receiving application is up and running in client-server communication?

Tags: network-programming, client-server

I am presently working on a client-server solution to transfer files to another machine via a socket network connection. Since I intend to do some evaluation on the receiving end as well I am assuming that I will need to have some kind of client or server programme running there, too.

I am fairly new to the whole client-server thing and therefore have the following elementary question:

My present understanding is that client and server will be two independent programmes running on two different machines. How would one typically ensure that the communication partner (i.e., the server when sending from a client and the client when sending from a server) is actually up and running on the remote machine that I want to transfer a file to?

So far, I have been looking into the following options:

1. In the sending programme include an ssh access to the remote
   machine and start an instance of the receiving programme on the
   remote machine.
2. Have the receiving programme run as a demon process on the remote
   machine. This would mean that the receiving programme should always
   be running on the remote machine. However, how would I know whether
   the process has crashed or has been shut down for some reason and
   how would one recover from that without option 1) above?

So, my main question is: Are there any additional options that might be worth considering?

Thanks for your view on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your client server messages are setup, a ping (I don't mean the ICMP ping, but the basic idea) message, where the server can respond with "I am alive" would help. This way at least you know the server end is running.

It is not uncommon in production environments using these that monitoring systems are put in place. Other options worth considering - xinet.d scripts - stuff that gets started on incoming connections.

There probably new ways to achieve the automatic start/restart or start on connection of this with systemd/systemctl but I am not familiar enough with them to give you the specifics.

A somewhat crude, but effective means may be a cron job that periodically runs a script to enforce keeping the service up.

Comment: Thanks, @Danny. This is a helpful post mentioning a few pointers I was unaware of so far. As for the cron job and the ping: Yes, of course these are indicators of the receiving party being up and running ... but do not offer any way to remedy a diagnosed unavailability. I'll look into the xinet.d scripts and the sytemd / systemctl you mentioned to see if they provide more functional scope.

Comment: I would, of course, welcome some additional views on how best to handle this standard challenge in client-server communication.